# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined ( login and register form on the one page )

Tags: javascript, python, flask

``` ``forms.py: ```

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField('Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
```

`routes.py:`

```
@app.route('/base', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def base():
    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('base'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('base')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('base'))


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('base'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('base'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

`base.html:`

```
<body>
    <div class="bg">
        {% block login %}{% endblock %}
        <div class="main">
```

`login.html:`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block login %}
    <div class="Log_in">
        <div class="close">
            <button class="close-button">
                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="input-place" id="log">
            <button class="google">        
                Continue with Google
            </button>
            <p>Or</p>
            <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name">
            <div class="light">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
                <div class="light-img"></div>
                <div class="light-yellow"></div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <button class="LogIn_button" name="submit">
                Log in
            </button>
            <div class="acc">
                <span class="acc_acc">
                    No account? 
                </span>   
                <span class="create">
                    Create one
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% block register %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

`register.html:`

```
{% extends "login.html" %}

{% block register %}

    <div class="input-place" id="reg">
        <button class="google">           
            Continue with Google
        </button>
        <p>Or</p>
        <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <div class="light">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
                <div class="light-img"></div>
                <div class="light-yellow"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="light">
                <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
            </div>
        </form>
        <button class="LogIn_button" name="submit">
            Create account
        </button>
        <div class="acc">
            <span class="acc_acc">
                No account? 
            </span>   
            <span class="create">
                Create one
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In result mistake:

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /base [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\app\routes.py", line 14, in base
    return render_template('register.html')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 152, in render_template
    return _render(app, template, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 133, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1301, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "\app\templates\register.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "login.html" %}
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\app\templates\login.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "\app\templates\base.html", line 24, in top-level template code
    {% block login %}{% endblock %}
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\app\templates\login.html", line 21, in block 'login'
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  File "\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 485, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

I can't figure out the error and fix it. tried through the tags from the Mega flask tutorial. like (form.username.label) but still didn't work. Most of the errors in others were that form=form in render_template was not specified, but I haven't a similar situation.

I will also explain what the main problem is. The difference between my code and that in the tutorial is that I render the login and registration on the same page and when the user selects the log in form, selects create account. Js code sets the value display: none for the login and display flex for the registration form.

Sent all required files above. I hope someone with more experience can help me)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: 3rd line in `routes.py` - `form` is not passed to the template.